# Setting QName parameters in xsltproc

Tags: xslt

I have an XSLT template that requires data passing in top-level parameters whose names are QNames, similar to this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:eg="http://example.com/" version="1.0">
  <xsl:param name="eg:foo"/>
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="$eg:foo"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I can't rename the parameters as their defined by an external standard, and I need to be able to work with third-party templates conforming to that standard.  I'd prefer to use `xsltproc` to process template as I'm already using it in the project and I'm familiar with its idiosyncrasies.  But I can't work out how to set a QName parameter from the command line.  What I really want is something like

```
xsltproc --xmlns eg http://example.com/ --stringparam eg:foo Something \
    template.xsl input.xml
```

... which should echo back the value of the eg:foo parameter.  (The contents of input.xml are irrelevant, so long as its well-formed XML.)  But I can't find anything like my hypothetical `--xmlns` command-line option.  Can anyone suggest how I might do this without hard coding the particular prefix that was used in `template.xsl`?

Comment: Can't you just use `--stringparam eg:foo 'Foo bar'`? Is that failing? I tried xsltproc in a Windows command prompt with various combinations like `--stringparam "eg:foo" bar`, `--stringparam eg:foo bar` and `--stringparam eg:foo "foo bar"` and all worked fine. Granted, the quote character might depend on the command line shell but I don't think you need to set up a namespace binding.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I can.  But how do I know what prefix to use?  The choice of a prefix is an implementation detail of the template, not part of its interface.

Comment: So you can't look at the namespace declarations in the XSLT stylesheet?

Comment: No.  The contents of the template is an implementation detail.  I could be using one of many different templates (including some written by third parties).  What they have in common is that they take a prescribed list of parameters.  That is their public interface, and what I'm coding to.  In the example above, I simply know that I need to set the `foo` parameter in the `http://example.com/` namespace.

Comment: I see. Saxon 9.7 has a feature "If the parameter name is in a non-null namespace, the parameter can be given a value using the syntax {uri}localname=value. Here uri is the namespace URI of the parameter's name, and localname is the local part of the name." to pass in namespaced parameters, I am not aware of anything like that for xsltproc.

Comment: Thanks, @MartinHonnen.  Yes, I was aware of that in Saxon.  For political reasons I'd prefer to avoid a Java XSLT processor, though I know Saxon is far and away the most feature-rich of the options, and I care about that far more than the efficiency libxslt offers.  As it seems there's no solution to this using xsltproc, I've submitted a patch to libxslt that allows parameters to be set using this Saxon-style format in addition to the current format.  In the mean time, it looks like I have to persuade my colleagues that Java isn't the fount of all evil.

Answer (score 1):

`xsltproc` does not have the ability to specify parameters with prefixed parameter names other than by using the using the prefix used in the template.  This is unfortunate because, per §4 of the [XML Namespaces specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-qualnames),

> Applications *SHOULD* use the namespace name, not the prefix, in constructing names whose scope extends beyond the containing document.

Here are three possible ways of avoiding assuming a particular choice of prefix.

**1:  Use a different XSLT processor**.  [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) supports setting parameters without knowing the prefix.  The syntax is:

```
java net.sf.saxon.Transform -s:input.xml -xsl:template.xsl \
  "{http://example.com/}foo='Something'"
```

**2:  Patch `xsltproc` to support it**.  [Libxslt bug 764195](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=764195) includes a patch that adds a Saxon-like syntax for setting parameters:

```
xsltproc --stringparam {http://example.com/}:foo Something \
  template.xsl input.xml
```

**3:  Look up the prefix binding**.  A simple XPath query can look up the prefix that's used in the template, and then construct the parameter name using that:

```
PREFIX=`xmllint --noout template.xsl --xpath \
          "name(/*/namespace::*[string()='http://example.com/'])"`
xsltproc --stringparam "$PREFIX:foo" Something template.xsl input.xml
```